# Cannot load such file, when using process substitution

Tags: bash, erb, process-substitution

Trying to use `erb` to load a library and render a config:

```
erb -r .env.rb config.erb
```

I want to conditionally update `.env.rb` so I thought I can use `sed` and use process substitution to achieve this, for example:

```
erb -r <( sed "s/level: 'trace'/level: 'info'/" .env.rb ) config.erb
```

But doing this gives me: `in 'require': cannot load such file -- /dev/fd/11 (LoadError)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Cyrus not sure what my question is missing? I have the exact code samples and the error that is associated with the example.

Comment: Thanks, I realize by now what you meant.

Comment: Did you try sending the output of your `sed` command to a file and then checking/using that file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes that would work; I want to this all in memory and not create an intermediate file.

Comment: Do you mean you think it would work? Or you have definitely tried it and checked it really does work?

Comment: I have tried it and it does work

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine `erb` either wants a "seekable" file (which a process substitution is not) or it looks at the file's extension, which seems unlikely unless it has its origins in Windows.

The following (untested) may get around both those issues, or at least give you an idea how to:

```
erb -r $( f=/tmp/$$.rb; sed 's/something/else/' .env.rb > $f; echo $f ) config.erb
```